# Insert a tex file pdf inside another tex file dynamically

Tags: compiling, include

Suppose that both `tex1.tex` and `tex2.tex` are two independent tex files in the sense that both compile and generate a pdf file independently. I would like to include the output of `tex2.tex` in the `tex1.tex` dynamically. I want to achieve this with one step of just compiling tex1.tex file ( and latex automatically do the second compile as a prerequisite step if I have referred to its result)

**My Question:** 
Is there any mechanism (like some instruction that can be added to `tex1.tex`) telling latex that when I am compiling `tex1.tex` it should first compile `tex2.tex` to its corresponding pdf, and then compile `tex1.tex` document with the tex2.pdf file included as a picture inside it.

**Update:**

I am adding example files for `tex1.tex` and `tex2.tex` to make the question more concrete:
suppose my `tex1.tex` is as bellow:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{Qartal}
\title{Inserting output of a tex file as pdf in one step}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
        I want to inset bellow this line my diagram from file (tex2.tex):
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

I want to inset bellow this line my diagram from file (tex2.tex):


\end{document}
```

and my `tex2.tex` file is as bellow:

```
% TikZ chains with labeled edges
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz , http://texblog.net
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}
%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzstyle{labeled}=[execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$]
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3em]
    { 0 & A  & B  & C  & 0 \\
      0 & A' & B' & C' & 0 \\ };
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-1-1);
    \chainin (m-1-2);
    { [start branch=A] \chainin (m-2-2)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_1}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi}}];
    { [start branch=B] \chainin (m-2-3)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_2}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi}}];
    { [start branch=C] \chainin (m-2-4)
        [join={node[right,labeled] {\eta_3}}];}
    \chainin (m-1-5); }
  { [start chain] \chainin (m-2-1);
    \chainin (m-2-2);
    \chainin (m-2-3) [join={node[above,labeled] {\varphi'}}];
    \chainin (m-2-4) [join={node[above,labeled] {\psi'}}];
    \chainin (m-2-5); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added example files.

Comment: Your example files are not really minimal. I am not sure if your are not after `externalization` really...

Comment: I will check later on if your files work with `bashful`

Comment: “I want to achieve this with one step of just compiling tex1.tex file” – If you are using a Unix system, the classical way to handle this dependency is to use the program **make**.  See for instance my [BSD Owl](https://github.com/michipili/bsdowl/blob/master/doc/LaTeXDocument.md) macros for **make** which have a nice support for LaTeX. These macros and **make** can also be used in other contexts. A more specialised tool which might be interesting for you is **latexmk**. If you work a lot with computers, you should quit the “learn ONE program and do EVERYTHING with it” approach, it is broken.

Comment: Have you considered a `Makefile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want: Use `bashful` package, which allows the execution of shell commands or external programs (I can test this only on Linux right now)

The external program(s)/commands must be 'enclosed' in a

```
\bash
...
\END
```

pair.

*Note: The compilation of the 2nd file is done each time when the outer wrapper document is compiled*.

**tex1.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}

\bash[stderr]
pdflatex tex2ext
\END

\includepdf{tex2ext.pdf}



\end{document}
```

**tex2ext.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: I omitted a screen shot, since `\blindtext` is quite well-known

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a job for shell escape (`\write18`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex \jobname2}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{\jobname2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I've used the same demo files as [Christian Hupfer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246314) but have run them together (using the `filecontents` environment) to make things a little smoother.

To get this to work you'll need to allow shell escape, so

```
pdflatex --shell-escape <filename>
```

at the command line or the equivalent in your editor. Note that there is a security risk with `\write18` as in theory any instruction could be passed by a third-party file.